# Sort multi-dimensional array by an element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort this array by a value that is in a sub table. I tried with the method Usort (), but impossible to sort.

```
    foreach ($res as $r) {
        usort($r, function($a1, $a2) {
            $v1 = $a1['WeekNumDay'];
            $v2 = $a2['WeekNumDay'];
            return $v1 - $v2; // $v2 - $v1 to reverse direction
        });
    }
```

In my array I would like to sort by key ['WeekNumDay'].

```
Array
(
    [R422] => Array
        (

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [WeekNumDay] => 19321
                    [Day1DeliveryTime] => 52932000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [WeekNumDay] => 18331
                    [Day1DeliveryTime] => 42770000
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [WeekNumDay] => 19305
                    [Day1DeliveryTime] => null
                )
        )

)
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: it seems to work. but you don't save results, use reference in foreach foreach ($res as **&** $r) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work if you just change these lines:

```
foreach ($res as $r) {
    usort($r, function($a1, $a2) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

to the following:

```
foreach ($res as $k => $r) {

    usort($r, function($a1, $a2) {
        // ...
    });

    $res[$k] = $r; // Edit the original array.

}
```

The reason it should work is because usort accepts the array as a reference, once you have sorted `$r` into the correct order you will then need to alter the original array, hence:

```
$res[$k] = $r;
```

Comment: "$res[$k] and $r essentially are the same thing, but one is the array and one is an element of the array." Heuh? No. By the way usort first argument is passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    usort($v, function ($a1, $a2) {
        return $a1['WeekNumDay'] <=> $a2['WeekNumDay']; //spaceship operator only php 7+
    });
    $arr[$k] = $v; //important to return the sorted array to the original container array
}
```

Note: [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) first argument is passed by reference, so passing `$arr[$k]` would work as well since php would figure where the container of $v.

Read more about [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/language.operators.comparison).